# IndexedDB onversionchange event not fired in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, indexeddb

I'm playing with the IndexedDB API from html5 spec in both Firefox and Chrome.

There something that's not working as expected I and want to share it here because I don't know if it's my fault or a browser bug.

According to the [API](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#widl-IDBDatabase-onversionchange), there's an event called **onversionchange** that's fired when you open a connection to a local database and the version number used is greater than the databases one. 
My problem is that this event is being fired in Firefox but not in Chrome.

Some sample code trying several modes:

```
var db;
var DB_VERSION = 5;
var openRequest = indexedDB.open("test_db", DB_VERSION);
openRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
    db = openRequest.result;
};
openRequest.onversionchange = function(event) {
    console.log("This is the place where I can change db structure");
};
openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
    console.log("This is the place where I can change db structure");
};
```

onversionchage event is not being fired even when I change the version number.

**UPDATE**
As *ebidel* has answered, Chrome implementation does not follow the currently specification so, in order to have a cross browser client code, we need to handle two situations: *onversionchange* event and *database.version* manual comparison.

Here are a couple on links with code example:
[Chromium google group](http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-discuss/browse_thread/thread/5d96ca12c2d092b6?pli=1) and 
[HTML5 Rocks!](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/)

Comment: why is that versionchange event on open request? it is on IDBDatabase instance, isn't it? http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#widl-IDBDatabase-onversionchange

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome's IndexedDB implementation is based off an older version of the spec which uses the older `setVersion` call rather than `onversionchange`/`onupgradeneeded`. Please star this issue: http://crbug.com/108223